# Rounding cmath complex numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have instances in my code where two complex numbers (using the `cmath` module) that should be exactly the same, do not cancel out due to the floating point precision of the base 2 system causing the numbers to deviate from each other by a small difference in value at some nth decimal place.

If they were floating numbers of sufficient size, it would be a simple matter of just rounding them to a decimal place where the value difference no longer exists.

How could I do the same for the real and imaginary parts of complex numbers represented using the `cmath` module?

e.g. The following two complex numbers should be exactly the same, how could I implement some code to ensure that the real and imaginary components of some complex number are rounded to the nearest ith decimal place of my choice?

```
(0.6538461538461539-0.2692307692307693j)
(0.6538461538461539-0.26923076923076916j)
```

One possible solution, recommended by jonrsharpe:

```
if abs(a - b) < threshold:
    a = b
```

Comment: Don't you just want to test `abs(a - b) < threshold`?

Comment: Ahh, that's a good way of implementing it yes. EDIT: Moved the syntax to the main post because I suck at formatting them in comments.

Answer (score 1):

"round" does not work directly on complex numbers, but it does work separately on the real resp. imaginary part of the number, e.g. rounding on 4 digits:

```
x = 0.6538461538461539-0.2692307692307693j
x_real = round(x.real, 4)
x_imag = round(x.imag, 4)
x = x_real + x_imag * 1j
```

Answer (score 0):

`Numpy` is defacto for numerical computing in python. Try [np.round()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html):

```py
import numpy as np
x = 0.6538461538461539-0.2692307692307693j
print(np.round(x,decimals=3))
print(np.round(x,decimals=3)==np.round(x,decimals=3)) # True
print(np.round(x,decimals=3)==np.round(x,decimals=4)) # False
```